# Simple trigger on salary

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I am new to sql and i have an employee table. I want to create a trigger so that no one can insert a new employee record with salary less than 200. I tried this code but it doesn't accept any record anymore and i see this error "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted." whatever the salary is.

This is my code

```
Create trigger Trig on Employees after insert
As
Begin
   if((Select count(EID) from inserted where salary<200)>0)
      Rollback
   else
      Commit
End
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you mean by saying "refuse"? It sounds like you want to delete existing data instead do not allow newly added data...

Comment: i want to create this trigger so that no one can insert a new employee record with salary less than 200

Comment: Are you submitting many rows at once, and this one is just the one you want rolled back?

Comment: In other words, are you just submitting one transaction at a time, or are there multiple transactions in this batch?

Comment: No, i want the trigger to work whether i'm submitting many rows at once or one row only.

Comment: But the problem is that when i'm trying to insert any record with (salary >200 or salary <200) the error above raises

Comment: i can do it with a check constraint on salary column , but i want to learn how to use triggers on insert . .

Comment: okay, your problem is with rollback.  see answer below.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific, so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why do you want to use a trigger rather than a check constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario trigger is not a good solution. try to add check constraint on Salary column. I think Check constraint is a good solution for your problem

```
ALTER TABLE Employees
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_Salary CHECK (Salary>=200)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When using rollback, it will treat the entire transaction as one, so if one of the inserts within the trigger meets the condition, it will unfortunately rollback all of the inserts within the transaction.

So, basically if you want to have it work this way, you won't be able to use `rollback` as an option or it will delete all of the other salaries from this transaction.

Here's the workaround, when one of the items meets the condition that you don't want after the insert, you will need to do something like this:

```
BEGIN
  IF ...
  DELETE FROM Table WHERE …
END
```